# Taxonomy term pages with multiple views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I currently use only one view with path `taxonomy/term/%` and without any vocabulary verification.

However, I would like to create two views: news and products (to implement different themes) linked to two vocabularies (1 per 1): news_categories and product_categories.

news_categories looks like:

> - category 1
> - category 2

product_categories

> - category 1
>
>   - subcategory 1
> - category 2
> - category 3
>
>   - subcategory 1

I don't want to allow displaying terms which are not from this vocabularies.
In addition I use pathauto to generating path, which sometimes are a few level dept.

I found a module called Taxonomy Views Integrator, but I'm not sure it's in 100% stable, so my question is that you are any other ways to handle many taxonomy term pages by views?

Answer (score 5):

Required modules: [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views), [Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto), [Simple hierarchical select](https://drupal.org/project/shs), [Taxonomy Views Integrator](https://drupal.org/project/tvi).

Create content type "food".

Create vocabulary "food" add some example terms:

```
+ fruits
  - apples
  - orranges

+ vegetables
  - carrots
  - potatoes
```

**Pathauto settings**

go to: `admin/config/search/path/patterns` and set the taxonomy term paths:

pattern for all food paths -> `[term:vocabulary]/[term:parents:join-path]/[term:name]`

Thanks to this pattern our food paths will look like: `food/fruits/apples` and may contain more than one parent, for example: `food/parent1/parent2/parent3/child`

Go to: `admin/structure/taxonomy/food` and check if all paths are setted up correctly. If not, edit them and check `Generate automatic URL alias`.

**Views**

Create view showing taxonomy terms from `food` vocabulary and add these three displays:

```
Page: Title: "`All food content`"
```

Path: `/food`

Relatonship:  `Taxonomy term: Content using Food terms`.

```
Page: Title: `Food category`
```

Path: `/food/%`

Relatonship:  `Taxonomy term: Content using Food terms.`

Contextual filter:  `(field_food_terms) Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)`

contextual filter settings: `depth = 1` (use: this page override)

Override title: `Food category - %1` This means, if we go to `food/fruits`, all items one level below `fruits` will be shown (all fruits)

```
Page: Title: `Food subcategory`
```

Path: `/food/%`

Relatonship:  `Taxonomy term: Content using Food terms.`

Contextual filter:  `(field_food_terms) Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)`

contextual filter settings: `depth = 0` (use: this page override)

Override title: `Food subcategory - %1`

There is no terms below, if we go to `food/fruits/apples`, all items with term name `apples` will be shown (only apples)

**Use Views to override term paths**

At the end you need to go back to: `admin/structure/taxonomy/food` edit each term and choose `Use view override.`

---

For each term you need to specify which view will be used to override, it's the main disadvantage of this solution.

[image]

### **Results**

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

### An example of article and blocks with relationship to the taxonomy.

[image]

Comment: If I need to specify a view for each term, the better option is to use TVI module.

Comment: No, TVI allows to set a view override for vocabulary or each term. At least, in the latest version. However, I wrote module **Taxonomy Views** for making links `taxonomy/[vocab]/[term]`. It's in verification queue now on drupal.org. If you install it, you doesn't have problem with making different views for taxonomy term pages. https://drupal.org/sandbox/daroPL/2063497

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe I don't fully understand the question.

**Goal**
Let's just assume the goal is to display, on taxonomy/term/%, a different view depending on which vocabulary that term is in. (whether there are pathauto aliases for this path, does not matter at all.)

**Views page + contextual filters?**
If you simply override the path with Views, this will be one views display for all terms, no matter which vocabulary - because they all share the taxonomy/term/% path.

**Alternative I: Taxonomy display module**
The [Taxonomy display](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display) module allows to customize the "associated content" display on taxonomy term pages. It allows to use a different view per vocabulary.

On "manage display" for the term, enable "Custom display settings" for the "Taxonomy term page" view mode, then for this view mode, configure the "Term page display".

**Alternative II: Display Suite + Taxonomy display + dynamic field**
What I often do instead is use [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds), and use the "Dynamic fields" feature. I think you need to enable ds_extras, ds_ui (both shipped with Display Suite) and work your way through the settings. Ideally, you should also enable views_content ("Views content pane").

This allows to not just have a dedicated views display per vocabulary and view mode, but it also allows to freely place one ore more such views in the ds layout, along with other fields.

The Taxonomy display module will only be used to hide the core list of associated content. Possibly this could be achieved with a custom module, up to you.

Quick guide:

- Download taxonomy_display, ds (7.x-2.*) and views. Enable ds, ds_extras, ds_ui, views_content, taxonomy_display.
- Create a view with a "Content pane" display and an argument taking the taxonomy term tid. This has more to it than I currently remember, so good luck figuring it out :)
- Go to admin/structure/ds/fields
- Add a dynamic field, name it whatever you want, e.g. "Tagged content". As the entity type, name "Taxonomy term"
- Go to admin/structure/taxonomy/categories/display (where "categories") is your vocabulary machine name)
- Enable "Use custom display settings for the following view modes: Taxonomy term page". Save.
- Go to admin/structure/taxonomy/categories/display/full
- In "Term page display" vertical tab at the bottom, set Term display = Core, Associated content display = Hidden. Breadcrumb and feed is up to you.
- In "Layout for categories in full", enable "One column" (under "Display suite"). Save.
- Move the "Tagged content" up in the "Content" region.
- On the dynamic field, click the cog-wheel icon, then "Select content", then in the dialog under "View panes" you can select the views display you just created. Configure the argument (Term id from url). Save.
- Repeat for other vocabularies.
- Make sure you disable the usual page view overriding taxonomy/term/%.

**Alternative III: Taxonomy display + Display suite + Views content DS**
The [Views content DS](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_content_ds) is a bit more convenient than Display suite dynamic fields. Up to you.

Comment: Hmm, this thing looks promising! https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display I think to remember these same options have been in DS core in the past. Not sure about that. https://drupal.org/node/2071029

Comment: The Alternative: Display Suite + dynamic field worked out perfectly but is there a way to restrict the node listing on the term page. I could not figure out any option to disable that. I know the same can be achieved using the taxonomy display module, but due to some specific reasons I need to stick to the Display suite module only. Please suggest.

Comment: I thought the term listing would already be disabled by using display suite? If not, I need to check in my old projects, next time I have a free moment.

Comment: @AnandSBahuguna I checked again in a few sites I made in the past. Turns out I used taxonomy_display to hide the automatic term display, and then display suite to embed the view as a dynamic field.

Comment: You could probably achieve the same (hiding the associated content list) with a custom module. Have a look at the code how taxonomy_display does it. Up to you.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks @donquixote. I will get to write some piece of code.