# contextual menus on drupal

Tags: routes, taxonomy-terms, views

I have some questions about Drupal menus. I am interested to have a Contextual Menu in sense that its links change depending where the user is.

I have a Taxonomy Menu and I would like to show in the menu only the term links to the level where the user was. For instance,

- Product

  - cat1
  - cat2

    - cat2.1
    - cat2.2
  - cat3

If I have the taxonomy shown above, if I click on product the menu should list only cat1, cat2 and cat3 but if I click cat2 menu should list only cat2.1 and cat2.2

How can do this on Drupal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're going to list `cat1, cat2, cat3` by visiting `Product` taxonomy term page, you need to define the path for `product/catX` and `product/catX/catXx/` as well. You can do that with Pathauto - here is [an example](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/82157/16739) of Pathauto settings + integration with views.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean literally only show that level, you can do this with Menu Block module using the Make the starting level follow the active menu item option.

If you mean that only that level should be expanded, you can do it like this: go to edit your Taxonomy Menu vocabulary. Under Taxonomy menu -> Structure options, uncheck Auto expand menu items.

But I'm not sure if Taxonomy Menu can be used with Menu Block like this.