# How to link taxonomy terms to custom views

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a vocabulary "destination' with 4 terms (dest1, dest2, dest3, dest4)
Then I have another vocabulary "category" with tons of terms (parents and childs)

I need to create a custom view (not from core) that will display the "destination" and also the "category" my content types are associated with (something like: /dest1/category/child/child, /dest3/category/child).

my setup in short:
- I have a view of type "Term", displaying as a block with one field set as Taxonomy: Term ID set to "Exclude from display" and another one set as Taxonomy: Term name (linked to its taxonomy term page)
- I have a second view of type "Node" (this is the default drupal taxonomy term view)
with a page display and a Taxonomy: Term ID argument

The setup works (for "category" anyway) until I try adding a destination to appear in front!! From what I understand I would need to create 3 other pages with a modify the paths but as soon as I try to change the path /taxonomy/term/% it defaults back to core display.

any help would be greatly appreciated (hope I gave enough information... not easy to describe a problem when confused)

Thanks

Comment: this [answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/82157/16739) might be helpful.

Comment: thanks, I'v seen that post already but it's not exactly what I need. I need a view to combine 2 different terms from different vocabularies... it would come out as /dest1(1rst voc.)/category(2nd voc.)/category-childs... any idea how to do this?